# How to get SalesForce data to Python Panda dataframes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, salesforce, soql

Currently we are taking SalesForce data in to CSV file and  reading this CSV file in Pandas using read_csv, to_csv methods. Do we have any other way to get data from SalesForce to pandas dataframe.

Answer (score 9):

With Python - you can download a package called Simple Salesforce and write SOQL queries to return data

https://github.com/simple-salesforce/simple-salesforce

Here's an example of how to do this:

```
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce
sf = Salesforce(username='<enter username>', password='<enter password>', 
     security_token = '<enter your access token from your profile>')

a_query= pd.DataFrame(sf.query(
     "SELECT Name, CreatedDate FROM User")['records'])
```

Comment: How can I find out the names of all the columns present? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, to display the information as a dataframe I had to use the following code:

```
# Import libraries
import simple_salesforce as ssf, pandas

# Create the connection
session_id, instance = ssf.SalesforceLogin(username='<username>', password='<password>', security_token='<token>', sandbox=False)
sf_ = ssf.Salesforce(instance=instance, session_id=session_id)

# Query to execute
sql_code = "SELECT id, name FROM main_table"

# Store query result as dataframe
information = sf_.query(query= sql_code)
table = pandas.DataFrame(information['records']).drop(columns='attributes')
```

Comment: How do you manage parent fields in your conversion to data frame?

Comment: I haven't experienced such thing before, I'm afraid I can't help.

Answer (score 2):

Adding up to the [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52164694/5322720),
the function below is also suitable for simple joins.

```py
def sf_results_to_dataframe(results, drop_index=True) -> pd.DataFrame:

    df = pd.DataFrame(results['records'])
    df.drop('attributes', axis=1, inplace=True)  # clean up from technical info
    df.set_index('Id', drop=drop_index, inplace=True)

    for table in ['Account', 'Contact', 'Lead', 'Opportunity']:
        if table in results['records'][0].keys(): # detect JOIN
            local_keys = list(results['records'][0][table].keys()) # keys from the joined table
            if 'attributes' in local_keys:
                local_keys.remove('attributes')

            global_keys  = [table + key for key in local_keys] # name for the fields in the output table

            # fields of the joined table and the record index
            table_records = [{'Id': record['Id'],
                              **{global_key:record[table][local_key] for global_key, local_key in zip(global_keys, local_keys)}}
                              for record in results['records']]
            df_extra = pd.DataFrame(table_records)
            df_extra.set_index('Id', drop=True, inplace=True) # match index
            df.drop(table, axis=1, inplace=True) # drop duplicated info
            df = df.merge(df_extra, left_index=True, right_index=True) # merge on index

    return df
```

Example:

```py
import pandas as pd
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce

SALESFORCE_EMAIL = '...'
SALESFORCE_TOKEN = '...'
SALESFORCE_PASSWORD = '...'

sf = Salesforce(username=SALESFORCE_EMAIL, password=SALESFORCE_PASSWORD, security_token=SALESFORCE_TOKEN)

query = """SELECT Id, Name, Account.Name
FROM Contact
LIMIT 1
"""

results = sf.query(query)
df = sf_results_to_dataframe(results)
```