# Fastest way to match 2 lists of dicts on a key value

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a script that retrieves user data from a CSV (~2.5m) and record data from Salesforce via API (~2m) and matches them based on a unique `user_id`.

For each user, I need the relevant `record_id` *(if it exists)*. There is a one-to-one relationship with users and records, so the `user_id` should only appear on 1 record.

To try and increase performance both lists are sorted ascending by `user_id`, and I break the loop if `record['user_id'] > user['user_id']` as that means there is no relevant record.

It's working, however it's slow when trying to match the 2 datasets taking ~1.5hrs. Is there a faster method of performing the matching to retrieve the relevant `record_id`?

Here is an example of the data, current function, and expected result:

```py
users = [
    {"user_id": 11111, "name": "Customer A", "age": 34, 'record_id': None},
    {"user_id": 22222, "name": "Customer B", "age": 18, 'record_id': None},
    {"user_id": 33333, "name": "Customer C", "age": 66, 'record_id': None}
]

records = [
    {"user_id": 11111, "record_id": "ABC123"},
    {"user_id": 33333, "record_id": "GHI789"}
]

upload = []
for user in users:
    for record in records:
        if user['user_id'] == record['user_id']:
            user['record_id'] = record['record_id']
            records.remove(record)
            break
        elif record['user_id'] > user['user_id']:
            break
    if user['record_id']:
        upload.append(user)

print(upload)
```

This outputs:

```py
[
 {'user_id': 11111, 'name': 'Customer A', 'age': 34, 'record_id': 'ABC123'}, 
 {'user_id': 33333, 'name': 'Customer C', 'age': 66, 'record_id': 'GHI789'}
]
```

Comment: Is one `user_id` mapped with multiple `record_id` in `records`?

Comment: Sounds like you want to create dictionaries with the user_id as the key and then use dictionary lookups.

Comment: @arsho no there should only be a single record per `user_id`. One-to-one relationship :)

Comment: How slow is "very slow", and how fast would be ok?

Comment: Is there a reason that you can't do this join in the original query? That would be the most efficient solution

Comment: @KellyBundy it currently takes ~1.5hrs to perform the matching. Even cutting that by 30mins would be nice.

Comment: @Nick Unfortunately not possible in this scenario. The user data comes from a CSV export and the records are from a Salesforce API call.

Comment: Ah, ok. Well this should only take *seconds*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a dictionary that maps from a user's id to its corresponding dictionary. Then, you can add the relevant `record_id` fields using a `for` loop. Finally, you can remove the entries without an assigned `record_id` using a list comprehension.

This doesn't require any preprocessing (e.g. sorting) to obtain speedup; the efficiency gain comes from the fact that lookups in a large dictionary are faster than searching a large list:

```py
user_id_mapping = {entry["user_id"]: entry for entry in users}

for record in records:
    if record["user_id"] in user_id_mapping:
        user_id_mapping[record["user_id"]]["record_id"] = record["record_id"]

result = [item for item in user_id_mapping.values() if item["record_id"] is not None]

print(result)
```

This outputs:

```py
[
 {'user_id': 11111, 'name': 'Customer A', 'age': 34, 'record_id': 'ABC123'}, 
 {'user_id': 33333, 'name': 'Customer C', 'age': 66, 'record_id': 'GHI789'}
]
```

With this being said, if you have to execute similar flavors of this operation repeatedly, I would recommend using some sort of a database rather than performing this in Python.

Comment: Alternatively for the `result = ` line, you could use a list comprehension: `result = [x for x in user_id_mapping.values() if x["record_id"] is not None]`.

Comment: Edited. Why is `filter()` slower than using a list comprehension, if I may ask?

Comment: I'd say mainly the function call overhead.

Comment: To be honest, my list comprehension suggestion was for sake of readability, although I accept that that may be subjective.

Comment: @alani Yes, I much prefer it for readability as well, I just focused on speed since that's the question's objective.

Comment: @KellyBundy Is the cost of the function call that significant if the list we're processing has millions of entries? I'm not trying to debate anything here, I'm genuinely curious.

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark I don't want to make any strong claims about speed without actually benchmarking it, but I guess that it is the calling the lambda function repeatedly which is the overhead. Clearly `filter` itself is only called once.

Comment: @alani Yes, the lambda function calls are what I meant. Looks like [more than twice as fast](https://tio.run/##dZJBasMwEEX3OsXgje3iFqcuIRi6aLPvBUIQSiwlAksyIxlSSs7ueqyQlMT9K@vr64004@47HJ2tVh0Og0JnIGgjdQBtOocBGqlE3wZOLoLw0zYyNvrQah@40m2QyFthdo3Iei/R5zWDUShDj3ZKZTGVxRScajhtEpR7hw3XTbIF7cG6AF/OygIiJP9TZO9Mh/IordfOzhXZ6CANKIcwfWgbIaDVZPxbbMtYDL7DZuL9JLSmXA0LUgGJFUaOy2Td@@CoDR/J6IoDmdVbAekVntaQKufSc/EAeyXNwT5vsMXqDkZXnGFVpDnW@sZaLu8vthOYntkWnmBVlrwsS8aoYZy6hcIeZFZdmkq26u2edh6HXMzMJJ4jhXLs5fSTZPnVJNhlbFevQ21DdknC83iwmHIvnNO7OI/RGMuH4Rc).

Comment: (Note I iterated over a repeated `users` list instead, as that was simpler to set up. It might also be slightly *faster* than iterating over dict values.)

Comment: Your answer is similar to my answer.. maybe a bit sexier in some ways ;)  But I think that your approach of first filling in the values and then later building the final list with the list comprehension is going to be slower.  You're iterating all n-million rows to find the users that have non-null records, but you already knew that when you iterated the first time, so the second iteration is not necessary.  In addition, you're doing more dictionary lookups than you really need to.  I'm sure that this is highly optimized in python but it still has a cost.

Comment: Sure, but at the end of the day, speed doesn't matter too much if this is a one-time job. If this operation needs to be done repeatedly or regularly, Python is likely not the best tool for this task (pulling directly from a database would be more desirable).

Comment: The question we're trying to answer.. the one that was asked.. is how to make it faster.

Comment: Right, I think there's a big difference between time on the order of hours versus the order of minutes. But for this case, I wouldn't be too worried about the difference between, say, 6.4 and 6.8 seconds, and even if I was, I would look into using something other than Python for this operation, which is what I discussed at the bottom of my original answer.

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark thanks for this answer, I have implemented this into our code and the time taken to match the data has dropped from ~2hrs to 1.5 seconds. Could not be happier!

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`pandas.read_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) to read your CSV data into a dataframe, and then `merge` that with the `records` on the `user_id` value:

```py
import pandas as pd

users = pd.read_csv('csv file')
records = pd.DataFrame('result of salesforce query')

result = users.drop('record_id', axis=1).merge(records, on='user_id')
```

If you want to keep the `users` which have no matching value in `records`, change the merge to

```py
merge(records, on='user_id', how='left')
```

To output the result as a list of dictionaries, use [`to_dict()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html):

```py
result.to_dict('records')
```

Note - it may be possible to execute your Salesforce query directly into a dataframe. See for example [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52117640/how-to-get-salesforce-data-to-python-panda-dataframes)

Answer (score 0):

Your approach isn't unreasonable.  But removing `record` after it's used has a cost.  Sorting your two lists ahead of time also has a cost.  These costs may add up more than you think they do.

One possible approach would be to NOT sort the lists, but instead build a dict of record_ids, eg:

```
rdict = { r['user_id']:r['record_id'] for r in records }
for user in users:
    user_id = user['user_id']
    record_id = rdict.get(user_id)
    if record_id:
        user['record_id'] = record_id
        upload.append(user)
```

This way you're paying the price once for building the hash, and everything else is very efficient.

Answer (score 0):

For scalability, you can use pandas dataframes, like so:

```
result = pd.merge(pd.DataFrame(users), pd.DataFrame(records), on='user_id').to_dict('records')
```

If you want to keep the entries which do not have a `record_id`, you can add the `how="left"` to the arguments of the `merge` function.